# Android Debug : Send sms from cmd to real device

Tags: android

I'm debugging an Android app that using SMS Sending function. To test this function, I need to send SMS to device that running this app. I test this app on real device. (that connects to my computer through adb)

My question is : How can I send a SMS message from computer to this device. It seems that I try this tutorial [tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/video-tut_-_simulating_incoming_phone_calls_-_sms_via_cmd-t135.html), but it doesn't work.

```
telnet
o localhost 5554 (or 5555)
```

I always receive "Cannot find host". So, please tell me how to this work.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your real device a phone connected to the network? Send the SMS from another phone or via an email gateway.

IIRC, 5554, 5555, etc. are the "phone numbers" of emulators. My notes on sending SMS messages to emulators say:

*To test SMS within the emulator, simply launch a second emulator and send the test messages to the emulator number, e.g. "5554"*

Maybe you can use telnet for this too, I don't know. If so, I need to update my notes.

p.s. Here are my notes on email-to-SMS gateways:

```
Verizon:      5551234567@vtext.com
AT&T:         5551234567@txt.att.net
T-Mobile:     5551234567@tmomail.net
Sprint:       5551234567@messaging.sprintpcs.com

Alltel        @message.alltel.com
Amp'd         @vtext.com
Boost         @myboostmobile.com
AT&T          @txt.att.net
Metrocall     @page.metrocall.com
Nextel        @messaging.nextel.com
Sprint        @messaging.sprintpcs.com
T-Mobile      @tmomail.net
US Cellular   @mms.usc.net
Verizon       @vtext.com
Virgin (USA)  @vmobi.com
Windstream    @windstream.net
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that adb listens to connections on port 5037

"telnet localhost 5037" connects to my computer.

Try
adb kill-server
adb start-server

When adb starts, it'll print the port number

Comment: yes. adb listens on port 5037. but when I type : o localhost 5037, it appear : "connecting to localhost" forever. (different from another port, that they says "cannot connect")

Comment: I think that port is for communications between adb and adb-server. I don't know what you can accomplish by connecting to it directly via telnet.

Comment: You can only telnet to android onto the emaulator, not a physical device